# How do I actually write/end an async method in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I get that I need to await thing in an `async` marked method to make it asynchronous, but I don't get how to actually end the hole it makes.

```
static async void Example()
{
    int t = await getIntAsync();
    WriteLine($"computer: {t}");
}
```

Since getIntAsync is marked async I have to await in that method or I get a warning. But oh no in the method I await on in getIntAsync I have to mark that as aasync, then unless there is an await in there I get a warning. And so on and so forth to infinity it seems. How do I just make it stop?

I've had a few people tell me to put

```
await Task.Delay(1000);
```

In my code, but I know the answer can't be as smelly as putting a delay of a second in all my production code.

A couple others said a task method to end it such as

```
static Task task()
{
  //code
}
```

But unless I mark that `async` it throws the same warning that got me into this confusion.  I know

```
static Task task()
{
  //code
  return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Technically it works, but again that seems too much of a code smell to have all over production.

I just don't get it...

EDIT:
Because it was asked for. I know its a very trivial method, but its also just one I'm using for practice.

```
    static async Task<int> getIntAsync()
    {

        Console.Write("Enter the number: ");
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        return n;

    }
```

Comment: Can you show what you _actually_ are trying to achieve? If you have no really asynchronous method inside, _why_ do you want to make the higher level method asynchronous at all?

Comment: [check msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx)

Comment: If you don't have anything to await, don't mark the method as async. Simple enough.

Comment: This code snip was just an example I've been using to try and learn. Its a small thing I'm trying to use to understand how to do bigger things with. I'll post it anyway for good measure.

Comment: If I understand you, you're concerned about when using async you basically have to chase it up the function call tree? The function or functions you want to be async need to be called via a separate thread. It can't be considered async if it's handled in the main thread, by the main thread, for the main thread.

Comment: please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). this could easily been googled: http://google.com/?q=example+async+await

Comment: There is nothing to await in what you're doing. In theory, I guess you *could* make console input an async process, but I'm going to say that's outside the scope of your learning example. Simplest answer is that this is not a great example to learn async with. Look to an example querying webpages, databases, or files.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot but then when I do have something to await how do I stop it from having this problem? The size of what my example method isn't my issue its how do I end need of more and more async methods needing an await on an async method that needs to await on an async method and so on.

Comment: @swe I have been goolging this for the past month, no where is my question explained. I just want to know how to not need to call await anymore at the end of the chain

Comment: @meeheecaan You don't.  When writing in an asynchronous paradigm you "async all the way up" so that your entire call stack is asynchronous.

Comment: @meeheecaan: You're looking at the problem backwards. Instead of trying to force asynchrony, you should *start* with something naturally asynchronous (usually an I/O operation), `await` it, and let `async` grow that way. Note that `async` will grow in the opposite direction of what you're trying to do. The "core" methods (which you usually do not have to write yourself) usually end up using I/O Completion Ports as I describe in my article [There Is No Thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is needed (async keyword is required and so is the await, it's simply best practice):

1. The Async keyword
2. The Await keyword
3. Some process that you want to work independently while the asynchorous process runs.
4. Typically, you return value comes from your await task (which should fill in the end hole).

Here is example using a StreamReader,

```
async Task<string> GetStringFromReaderAsync()
{
  Streamreader sr = new StreamReader("filename.txt");

     Task<string> getStringTask = sr.ReadLineAsync("filepath");

    //Allow user to continue with some other work.
     DoFileLookup();

  string result = await sr.getStringTask();

  return result.ToString();

}
```

More information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readlineasync(v=vs.110).aspx

More about Async and Await: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx

Comment: But how does ReadLineAsync handle it? What does it do to plug the hole? What does it await on, and how does it end its await chain? Thats what I don't get.

Comment: I apologize please view the answer again, `string result = await sr.ReadLineAsync()`, should be `string result = sr.getStringTask();`

Comment: So, the getStringTask is just the asynchoronous task that runs the current thread, allowing operation to continue while this thread runs. The hole is plugged, which I think you mean, the result of the await, is when that thread is complete or done processing. Once that thread is complete, the "await chain" ends, thus giving you the result that user was waiting for while doing other operations.

Comment: Check my second link for what happens to the async method getStringTask, essentially, the program can continue running while doing this process by returning control to the user, without freezing the program, or making the user wait.

Comment: Stated in the second link: "Asynchrony proves especially valuable for applications that access the UI thread because all UI-related activity usually shares one thread. If any process is blocked in a synchronous application, all are blocked. Your application stops responding, and you might conclude that it has failed when instead it's just waiting"

Comment: The `ReadLineAsync` is waiting(awaiting on `getStringTask`) for the `sr.getStringTask` to finish the current thread(task).

Answer (score 4):

What is confusing here is that you don't really do something *asynchronous*. `Console.ReadLine()` is a synchronous method. Simply typing `async` or `await` somewhere does not magically make this asynchronous.

Since this code is only for testing and learning, one way to make it asynchronous is to put it on another thread using [`Task.Run()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) (I would not suggest this for many cases in production code):

```
static Task<int> getIntAsync()
{
    Console.Write("Enter the number: ");
    return Task.Run(() => int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

There is no `async` keyword needed here as you are not awaiting something. You just return a `Task<int>` that is completed when the user has entered a value and that value was parsed.

And your `Example()` method then works like that:

```
static async void Example()
{
    int t = await getIntAsync();
    WriteLine($"computer: {t}");
}
```

When the `await` is hit, the control flow is returned to the caller and the rest of this method (the assignment to `t` and the call to `Console.WriteLine()`) are scheduled as a continuation that is executed when the `Task<int>` returned by `getIntAsync()` has finished.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> static async Task<int> getIntAsync()
> {
>
>     Console.Write("Enter the number: ");
>     int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
>     return n;
> }
> ```

This will run synchronously as there is **no await statement And no awaited call to an async method**

the general idea is this

```
   public async Task<int> ExecuteAsync() //Method return type is Task<int>
   {
      // Error: return type is not int. Return type is Task<int>
      return db.SaveChangesAsync(); 

      // OK: returns a task handle that you can await on in you code that called ExecuteAsync()
      // you thread continues processing in your calling function until you try to read the value from this return statement.
      return await db.SaveChangesAsync(); 

      // Ok. Your Thread leaves here and returns when result available.
      // no further Processing done in calling function
      return db.SaveChangesAsync().Result; 

      // Ok. This is not required in this case, 
      // but if you have an async method that has multiple return points, 
      // and one of them does not depend on an async method, you can wrap
      // the output e.g. return await Task.FromResult(0); 
      return await Task.FromResult(db.SaveChangesAsync().Result); 

      return 0; //also ok.
   }
```

Adding on to the other answer below.

```
static async Task<int> GetIntAsync()
{
    Console.Write("Enter the number: ");
    return await Task.Run(() => int.Parse("1"));
}
```

This approach makes something that runs synchronously to be wrapped in a task. However you should never do this (unless of course you know what you are doing) as this spawns another thread. One use case where I have used this is for offloading in webservers but otherwise generally its a bad idea. So while you may have begin with the intention of have maximum utilization of a single thread, you have now ended up with two thread working.